# java spring email - "From" field issue

Tags: java, spring, email

Scenario: User submits contact form with her email address. The email I receive should be "from" the email filled in the contact form. What I get instead is the gmail (foo@gmail.com) account I configured in spring context, although the **setFrom** is set properly in code as following:

```
public void sendContactNotification(final ContactForm contactForm) {
      MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
             MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
             message.setTo(contact@foo.com);
             message.setFrom(contactForm.getEmail());
             message.setSubject("New contact message " + contactForm.getTopic());
             message.setReplyTo(contactForm.getEmail());
             message.setSentDate(new Date());
             Map model = new HashMap();              
             model.put("newMessage", contactForm);

             String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                velocityEngine, "velocity/new_contact_message.vm", "UTF-8", model);
             message.setText(text, true);
          }
       };
       this.mailSender.send(preparator);      
}
```

In Spring context the sender is configured as following:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="username" value="foo@gmail.com" />
<property name="password" value="password" />

<property name="javaMailProperties">
   <props>
          <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
          <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
       </props>
</property>
```

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Gmail's SMTP server isn't willing to do that for you.

Comment: Hi SLaks, so the code it's right, but I should change my email provider... Thanks